How does one write a horror fight scene where a person has to fight someone that is way stronger bigger and tougher than them
So I'm trying to write some fight scenes for fanfics I'm working on revamping and I've decided,"Ya know, I should just ask the big experts rather than just random discord friends." So that's why I'm here. The two fight scenes are a baby going up against a slasher villain who wants to kill her and use her soul for the man he worships to become even stronger, and another scene is the same baby being forced by an evil corporate CEO to dismantle an entire robot held together by spring locks. If you can't tell this is a FNAF fanfic. So the reason I ask is because I want it to stay relatively realistic and I wanna show in both circumstances how the baby figures stuff out. I should mention the baby is very booksmart due to spending since the day she was born reading and learning within an old crusty library.  Her name is Hellen and she's supersmart yes. However, she still has the mentality mannerisms and behaviors a baby would normally have despite being that smart so I have to figure out how to make these fight scenes realistic, horrific, and awesome without it coming off as, bad writing or Mary sue, or just plain old style over substance. The reason I ask here is because I want advice that is concise in order to improve the quality of my work.

A baby is around 12-18 months old. She can't be booksmart at that age. She can't fight anything, either.

Never did i say that there wouldn't be some amount of unrealisticness. However, this doesn't just apply to the child aspect. This is about a fight scene where the victor doesn't win with raw strength but strategic planning and positioning.

What sort of contest, physical or intellectual, would put an adult and an infant on equal fighting terms?

This isn't a contest though, these are life or death situations.

If you want your audience to in any way believe in the story/scenes, you will probably have to reconsider that character being a baby. If you're not simply using the term incorrectly - as in you mean someone a few years old, I'd say 8-10 is 'realistic' for approaching things as enemies to fight or outsmart...

I've written an answer - one that may fit others attempting to create a similar setup with an imbalance in power etc. and one that outlines the work that should go into making the story realistic in terms of the small/weak character actually standing a chance.

@storbror By his first comment, I think Rising Writer actually wants a 1 year old prodigy go against a killer.

@CarlosMartin Yeah, I kinda got that impression too... I hope we've successfully persuaded them to age their character differently.

Initial problem
As I and others have commented, an actual baby seems like an impossible character to put in those situations / scenes.
I'll call the character the kid.
Approach to ' strong enemies' vs. 'weak character'
When it comes to approaching the 'stronger and tougher' enemies, you should set them up as realistic as possible when it comes to their strengths and weaknesses.
For instance, a very big 'person' (creature) may have bad manoeuvrability/flexibility or speed, and lack the ability to enter/get through tiny openings etc. - this could give the kid an advantage (if you set the stage correspondingly). Meaning, you need to place these characters in locations where the different qualities of the characters make this difference in outcome.
The enemies may not be super intelligent, and could perhaps be easily distracted or confused. With this, the kid could use items to lure the bigger ones away or into places and perhaps trap them. Also, if the enemies are very 'smash smash smash' and not very situationally aware, the kid may use the environment as a way to 'attack' the enemies, perhaps using ropes/hooks/shelves/boxes/barrels or elements such as electricity/water/fire and so on...
Believable backstory
In order for us to believe that the small character is fit to handle these obstacles/fights/dangers, we should initially get to know the kid as an observant and reflective character, one that thinks in practical solutions and problem-solving. A child of a few yeas, say from 5 or 6 may begin such tendencies, and if they've had such approaches to the world around them, when they are the age of 9-10, they might be able to use such skills to survive against large and dangerous but primitive 'enemies'. If they've been brought up with intensive practical problem-solving routinely, they could be very fit to survive against bigger threats.
If the kid grew up hearing about or witnessing interactions or scenes with the aforementioned enemies, they may have some initial ideas of how to 'beat' them. They could then built on those skills and adapt them to new environments and other types on enemies as the story continues.
The horror genre
In order for the story to be horror, it should be scary. One of the ways to make the story scary is for us, the reader, to fear something, whether or not the character(s) (here the kid) does so or not. The kid may come to care about other characters and witness them lose the fight against the enemies. We may witness or hear about how the kid lost its parents, and so on. If these informations or scenes portray the danger(s) that the kid will face, we will then fear for the life or well-being of the kid...
The more 'loss' the kid experiences, the worse of an outcome we expect from the world. For instance, the initial 'fights' with the big baddies should perhaps result in the kid barely making it out alive, and perhaps even severely hurt. That way we gain a respect of the danger that the big baddies represent. This will also make it satisfying once the kid actually beats the big baddies.

Mr Magoo / Fate is with you. The character despite not having normal adult levels of cognition has the fates on their side.
As they artlessly move around trying to avoid the monster they trigger situational effects- ladder, hole-in-the-ground- that entrap or defeat the monster. This happens for them because they are being true to themselves and thus destiny ensures they live.
There’s been a few shows with “baby” characters too. Risk: could become a pinball protagonist (no agency).
